# Why does my calendar control disappear when I enter edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my project, I'm tracking deadlines where I have an expected date and an actual date. All information is stored in a SQL Server 2008 database.

The expected date is always entered, but my actual date wasn't. This was giving me an error when I entered edit mode in my `GridView`, so I set all actual dates to a fixed date (1990-01-01).

I was going to check for that fixed date in my `RowDataBound` function. If found, I would then replace that date with an empty string (of course only in the `GridView` and not in my DB). But when I do so and enter edit-mode, my calendar control disappears. How can I work around that?

Edit:

**ASPX-code:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual Date" SortExpression="Actual_Date">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Calendar ID="cal_act_date" runat="server" 
            VisibleDate='<%# DateTime.Now %>' 
            SelectedDate='<%# Bind("Actual_Date") %>' BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" 
            Width="200px">
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:Calendar>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_act_date" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual_Date", "{0:d}") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void GV_Milestones_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testServer"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd_getActDate = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [ms_tr_actual_date] 
                                                  FROM [NSBP].[dbo].[tbl_milestones_tracking]
                                                  WHERE [ms_id] = " + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + 
                                                  @" AND [ms_tr_bill_run] = '" + DDL_billrun.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
        string value = Convert.ToString(cmd_getActDate.ExecuteScalar());

        if (value.ToString() == "01/01/1990 00:00:00")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[7].ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can u share your code ? you have to check whether you are in EDIT mode or not, if your are in edit mode, then you need to find controls.

Comment: I've tried adding your TemplateField to a test GridView and it works fine. Are you getting any exceptions in RowDataBound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first check if date is "1-1-1990" then show empty string in selected date property.
You can do this by using below code :-

```
SelectedDate='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Actual_Date")).ToString() == "01-01-1990" ? "" : Eval("Actual_Date")  %>'
```

// "01-01-1990"  is date , you entered in database